# How to get a hidden button value using php which is not inside the form tag

Tags: php

How to get a hidden button  value using php  which is not inside the form tag?
Please let me know the solution as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: y u dont want to use it inside form?

Comment: *Please let me know the solution as soon as possible.* - **NO**

Comment: Please do some research as soon as possible.

Comment: I would try with DOMDocument/Xpath

Comment: Please hire a professional that does the work for you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Without javascript it is impossible.
With javascript you can write own .onsubmit() handler and inject this element into form data.
Also you can use ajax to process form submit and retrive and handle response.

Example on JS with JQuery Lib .onsubmit() and element injection:

example.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    if(sizeof($_POST)>0)
        var_dump($_POST);
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_field_1" value="hidden value">
    <form action="example.php" method="post" name="form1">
        <input type="text" name="visible_text_field">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('form[name=form1]').on('submit', function(e){
            var hidden_input = $('input[name=hidden_field_1]');
            $('form[name=form1]').append( hidden_input );
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output after input and submit:

```
array(2) {
  ["visible_text_field"]=>
  string(10) "test input"
  ["hidden_field_1"]=>
  string(12) "hidden value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, you can get the value like this,

```
var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("mytext").value
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options 
going jQuery

```
var buttonval = $("#buttonid").val();
```

going with javascript

```
var buttonvalue = document.getElementById("buttonid").value;
```